# How to play sound after each network request is successful?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I want to play a sound after each network request is successful. I have some objects that I want to send to the server using a for loop. In each iteration I'm sending a request to the server and after each request is complete, I want to play a sound.

I've tried this:

```
for object in objects {
   sendObjectToServer(object)
}

func playSound() {
  let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sound", withExtension: "mp3")!
  let player = try! AVAudioPlayer(url)
  player.play()
}

func sendObjectToServer(object: Object) {
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with url: object.url) {(data,response,error) in
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
          playSound() // doesn't play sound synchronously
        }  
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the main thread for background-related operations. Only update your UI in the `Dispatch.main.async` code:

Try this on a physical device (tested and worked)

```
import AVFoundation

for object in objects {
   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
     sendObjectToServer(object)
   }
}


var player: AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sound", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)            
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        /* The following line is required for the player to work on iOS 11. Change the file type accordingly*/
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

        /* iOS 10 and earlier require the following line:
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3) */

        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.play()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func sendObjectToServer(object: Object) {
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with url: object.url) {(data,response,error) in
      // Custom Logic
      playSound()
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is this gonna play a sound each time the request is successful? Isn't it gonna to reinstantiate the player object before it even gets to run the play function?

Comment: The volume reduces if I send more than 3 objects.

Comment: Then move the player variable to the ‘playSound()’ function.

Comment: Its a bit better but not that good still :/ Is it possible to play sound and then during the second iteration if the sound hasn't finished playing, add it to the queue so that it can be played after the avplayer's done playing?

Comment: I did use AVQueuePlayer but it expects an array right away when its instantiated.

Comment: You may want to wait until the previous audio is finished, and then queue another one.

Comment: How would I do that?